# Changing compiler optimization levels doesn't change the compiled binary

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, compiler-optimization

I have been using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` toolchain to cross compile a binary to `arm`. The strange thing is I don't get any differences in the compiled binaries though I change the optimization level. Even I was following [this](https://developer.arm.com/docs/100748/latest/using-common-compiler-options/selecting-optimization-options) documentation from 'arm' and took the same source from it indicated below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

   int x =10, y =20;
   int z;
   z =x+y;
   return 0;

}
```

I even went through the `man` page and I think I am using the optimization flag correctly. This is the exact code I use to compile.

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O1 -o test test.c
```

However, the 'test' object file produce doesn't change (The size of the compiled binary is the same) regardless of me changing the optimization level as indicated in above arm documentation . What could be the reason for it? Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `The size of the compiled binary is the same` - how did you measure the size? Why would you expect it to change?

Comment: I used `ls -al` to get the size. According to the `arm` documentation that I was going through, the size does change as the optimization level goes up. But in my case it didn't change even for the highest optimization level regardless of using the same source code in the arm documentation

Comment: Have you inspected your two binaries with objdump? Maybe the `text` section contains a lot of padding?

Comment: `According to the arm documentation` - what documentation? Are you sure they are mentioning size _of file_, and not like size of .bss section or anything else? An optimization option may increase the size of executable, because compiler may sacrifice size for speed. You can't make assumptions like "it will be smaller, always". Compiler may insert padding `nop` instructions to align your instruction to some boundary.

Answer (score 1):

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O0 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e24dd014    sub sp, sp, #20
   c:   e3a0300a    mov r3, #10
  10:   e50b3010    str r3, [fp, #-16]
  14:   e3a03014    mov r3, #20
  18:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
  1c:   e51b2010    ldr r2, [fp, #-16]
  20:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
  24:   e0823003    add r3, r2, r3
  28:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
  2c:   e3a03000    mov r3, #0
  30:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  34:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  38:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  3c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O1 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

and the rest of the optimization levels should produce the same result as -O1 since this is dead code and all of it gets removed with simple optimization.

The key here is when you say "binary" I assume you mean the output file created by

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O1 -o test test.c
```

that "test" file contains a lot of stuff, for a simple program like this almost none of it is actual code.

If you examine the size of the object file (so.o above) rather than the linked binary you should see the difference or use arm-whatever-objcopy -O binary and you "might" see a difference there, it might also be in the noise there too.

880 bytes for the -O0 object, 824 bytes for the -O1, but as you can see in the 
disassembly there is good sized differences as a result of optimization.